# Verifying distributivity of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

How can I efficiently verify distributivity holds for a 4-element field?

I already have the additive groups for my fields ($Z_4$ and $Z_2 \times Z_2$), but now I need to come up with a multiplication table and make sure distributivity works. I see no other way than checking every combination.

Comment: “Field**S** of order 4?  You know there is a unique field for every prime power order, right?  Their additive groups are always a product of prime power groups.

Comment: If you know the uniqueness I mentioned (I’m aware that may not be available to you) then you could get distributivity for free by constructing a field of 4 elements that is a quotient of a ring.

Comment: i will probably figure out that when i DO verify distributivity, they will be the same field. but i first have to try doing distributivity and it seems like it is a very laborious task.

Comment: they cannot possibly be the same field of their additive groups are nonisomorphic.

Comment: oops, i meant that only ONE would actually work as a field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $F$ is a four-element field, then its multiplicative group has order $3$, hence it is cyclic.

Therefore $F=\{0,1,a,a^2\}$. Let's try reconstructing the Cayley table for the addition. We know that $x+x=0$, because the characteristic must be $2$, as subrings of fields have no zero-divisor.

Note that $1+a\ne a$ and that $a+a^2$ has to be different from $a$ and $a^2$. However it cannot be $0$, otherwise $a(1+a)=0$, which is a contradiction. Hence $a^2+a=1$. Similarly, $1+a=a^2$ and the Cayley table can be filled in:
$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
+   &   0 &   1 &   a & a^2 \\ \hline
0   &   0 &   1 &   a & a^2 \\
1   &   1 &   0 & a^2 &   a \\
a   &   a & a^2 &   0 &   1 \\
a^2 & a^2 &   a &   1 &   0
\end{array}
$$
This proves that, if a four-element field exists, it is unique up to isomorphism.

A four-element field exists, namely $F_2[X]/(X^2+1)$, where $F_2=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Thus you *need not* verify distributivity from the Cayley tables.